# Razor syntax For Each with String.Format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

I am new to Razor syntax in ASP.MVC4 and need to format a string within a loop to provide a run time path to the correct image file.

I am having problems in formatting the string within the For Each list item. Can you have a look at the below and let me know what I'm missing.

```
<ul class="column">
    @For Each item As modeltype In Model
        @<li>
            @Code
                dim itemImage as string = String.Format("../../Images/{0}.png", @item.MajorAssembly)    
            End Code
            <a href="#"><img src="@itemImage"/></a> 
        </li>
    Next            
</ul>
```

Comment: Is this code sample correct it looks malformed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the @ off of @item.MajorAssembly.  When you are inside an @Code block, everything is considered code and additional @'s are unnecessary.

```
<ul class="column">
@For Each item As modeltype In Model
    @<li>
        @Code
            dim itemImage as string = String.Format("../../Images/{0}.png", item.MajorAssembly)    
        End Code
        <a href="#"><img src="@itemImage"/></a> 
    </li>
Next            
</ul>
```

Also, if you want, you could put the String.Format call directly into the src like this:

```
<ul class="column">
@For Each item As modeltype In Model
    @<li>
        <a href="#"><img src="@String.Format("../../Images/{0}.png", item.MajorAssembly)"/></a> 
    </li>
Next            
</ul>
```